# Backbone router strange behaviour

Tags: backbone.js, routes, marionette

I have defined backbone router:

```
MyApp.router = new (Backbone.Marionette.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    "/m/:id": "openMovie",
    "m/:id": "openMovie"
  },

  openMovie: function(id) {...}
});
```

My html has link like `/m/123`. When I click this link backbone doesn't trigger `openMovie` function - browser opens new page. Why doesn't backbone use history api in this case? How can I fix it with backbone or marionette?

Answer (score 2):

Backbone `pushState` support is opt-in. When you've initialized all your routers, [call](http://backbonejs.org/#History)

```
 Backbone.history.start({pushState: true})
```

The default behavior is to listen to `hashchange` events using url `#fragments`, so if you don't want to use pushState, define you links with a hash url:

```
<a href="#/m/123"></a>
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using `pushState: true`. When I click link the whole page is refreshed... I need only 'openMovie' to be triggered

Comment: @fedor.belov, quirky. Sorry to say, then I don't know what could be the problem. Are you initializing your router before calling `Backbone.history.start`?

Answer (score 1):

and if you want the compatible version:

```
if (!Backbone.History.started) {

       // Enable pushState for compatible browsers
       var enablePushState = true;  

       // Disable for older browsers
       var pushState = !!(enablePushState && window.history && window.history.pushState);

       Backbone.history.start({ pushState: pushState });
     }


>
```